# How to read characters of string or character array without using length function

Tags: c#

I want to read all the characters from the string without using the built in functions.I tried the below.

```
        char[] str ={ 'k','r','i','s'};            
        for ( int i = 0; str[i]!='\0'; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(str[i]);
        }
```

But I get an exception because unlike in c I don't see the string here ends with a null character.
Is there any other way (apart from using built functions/try catch block in case of exception) I can read all the characters of the string ?

Comment: A char array is not a string. A string is a string. And strings in C# are not null terminated. And Length is not a function, and it is O(1) to compute, not O(n). I suspect you are a C programmer; remember, C# is a different language.

Comment: Btw why do you want to do that

Comment: "without using the built in functions" why?

Comment: @Eric: How is it "not a function"?  It's a property getter method, which will be inlined, but it's still a method.

Comment: @BenVoigt: array lengths are generated using the `ldlen` instruction, not a method invocation.

Comment: @Eric: Then I guess it's both... or would `typeof(T[]).GetProperty('Length').GetGetMethod()` fail?  Does the C# compiler magic look for calls to this method and replace them with `ldlen`, or does it recognize certain patterns in source code and bypass the normal property access handling?  Now I wonder if the JIT generates (with inlining) as good code for this method call as it does for `ldlen`.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Regarding your first question: I can think of a good way to find out what happens when you run that code: run the code.  Re: your second question: I don't understand the difference between the two options you are describing; they sound like the same thing to me.

Answer (score 3):

In c# arrays have `Length` property:

```
char[] str ={ 'k','r','i','s'};            
for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(str[i]);
}
```

Otherwise you can use `foreach` which will enumerate all characters in an array.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `i < str.Length`.. ?

Comment: Yeah, forgot it; Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If what you really want is to display the string that the characters in the char array produce:

```
char[] mychars = { 'k', 'r', 'i', 's' };
Console.WriteLine("Your characters form the following string: " + new string(mychars));
```